# What's the minimum Android API level for using new Google's Jetpack components

Tags: android, android-room, android-livedata, android-jetpack

I had started to learn RxJava that I knew there's some new Google's components like LiveData, Databinding, etc. I want to know what is the minimum Android's API level to use them. Can I leverage them for example in an older APIs like 21 or 23?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right from the Docs https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/.

> Starting with Support Library release 26.0.0 (July 2017), the minimum supported API level across most support libraries has increased to Android 4.0 (API level 14) for most library packages.

Also Check out [Version Support and Package Names](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/#api-versions).

And yeah you are good to go with `LiveData` all the way down to `API-14`.

Answer (score 0):

of course you can use api level 21
it will not restrict you for api level so much