# How to use Xamarin.Android.Arch.Lifecycle.Extensions with API Level 21. Doesn't add reference to project

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

Want to use ViewModel to share data between fragments in a ViewPager. I installed Xamarin.Android.Arch.Lifecycle.Extensions, for an app that is targeting API Level 21, but it is not allowing me to reference it with `using Xamarin.Android.Arch` <-- Arch does not exist in Android

It is installed in Nuget Package Manager, but is not showing up in my list of references. When I run `Update-Package -reinstall`, it says those packages are already installed, and I see that my other Nuget installed packages disappear from References, and then reappear as they are reinstalled, but the Architecture one does not.

.
.

[image: Show that it is installed using Nuget Package Manager]

[image: Show it is not listed in References]

Looking at the package details in the package manager, are these dependencies below important? What do they mean? When I look at the properties for my Mono.Android reference.. it shows Version 0.0.0.0 and Runtime Version v4.0.30319.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

About the Xamarin.Android.Arch.Lifecycle.Extensions, there are some dependencies,

You can see from the last screenshot you provided.

For last screenshot, it is version 1.1.1.1, it can download and works on Android 6.0,7.0,7.1,8.0,8.1, 9.0. About Android version, you can get this info from project--project properties--Android Manifest--Target android version.

If you want to use this package in android 5.0(API 21), I think it failed.

Comment: What about the answers posted to this stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54780197/whats-the-minimum-android-api-level-for-using-new-googles-jetpack-components/54780242#54780242.. They seem to be saying that Android JetPack, which I thought ViewModel was part of, is supported to API 14?

Comment: @SweetTomato,According to this thread, it just means that LiveData can be used in api 14, about Xamarin.Android.Arch.Lifecycle.Extensions, I think you should follow these dependencies.